# Installing Freetype 2.5.3 Linux

Tags: c++, linux, freetype2

I have a C++ project which uses FreeType 2.5.3 and which I need to compile on linux (Kubuntu)
First I have Freeype already installed but it is older version (2.3.5).

1. I used command from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/freetype2.html)  to compile and install the lib headers and lib files.
2. Then in isr/include/freetype2 I have found that the headers are still the old one.I copied there the headers from the new version.

Now I see errors coming from ftheader.h that it doesn't find `FT_STROKER_H` ,`FT_LCD_FILTER` and more header macros.

Are there some additonal steps I have missed here?